# Documentation new topic: Where did my draft go?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-proposals, documentation-editor, documentation-drafts

I requested a new topic in the Ruby language documentation, then proceeded to write a full set of examples for it in the draft.

But now I can't figure out how to get back to that draft, and I can only see the request to create the topic in the list of requests, the draft has gone missing.

Is the draft lost?  If not, how can I get back to the draft?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1795483/david-ljung-madison?tab=documentation&sort=topicdrafts Over here?

Comment: Ah, I went to the requests - didn't realize that there was a drafts tab in our user profile.  Want to make that an answer so I can select it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find your current drafts at

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=topicdrafts